# Formatting of references

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, formatting, citing

I have a problem with bibtex etc. If I try to printout the references, I will get something like this:
[image]

But I want this (like in all papers)

[image]

Can someone say which usepackages I should use.
Should I write everything in the main file or should I do a separate .bib file for my references?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more about how you create your bibliographies at present. Assuming you're willing to go with BibTeX, It very much looks likes you're interested in the `alpha` bibliography style.

Comment: Hey Mico, to be honest, I have lots of difficulties with the BibTex, I have no good source. I did not create my bibliogrpahies until now. I am open to learn every method to reach the above aim. I am reading now: bibtex, natbib (a package for use with bibtex) and biblatex are the three types, where biblatex is the best one.

Comment: There's some terminological confusion here that's common but should be avoided if possible. BibTeX and biber are external programs; natbib and biblatex are LaTeX *packages* that work (mainly) with BibTeX and biber, respectively. biblatex and biber are still being actively developed, whereas BibTeX and natbib have been pretty much frozen for many years. However, what is "best" for you cannot be reduced to the length of the feature sets. It also matters what your co-authors use: If they all use natbib and BibTeX, it's to your advantage to learn how to use natbib and BibTeX as well.

Comment: Hey Mico, I am the only author and my bibliography is at most a page long. So Biblatex would be fine here?

Comment: Biblatex with biber :D

Comment: I think the importance of the choice between natbib/bibtex and biblatex/biber is grossly overemphasized. Honestly, if everybody spent less time on this supposed conflict and spent more time on making sure that the *contents* of their bibliographies are correct, we'd all be better off. So, work mostly on getting the contents of the bib file in shape.

Comment: Hey Mico, thank you very much. I spent more time now to get a better overview. Mostly I read that biblatex+biber is recommended.

Comment: Depending on where you look, you'll easily find recommendations for both routes. If you're fine with learning `biblatex`, more power to you, absolutely. I'm starting to feel, though, like I'm getting dragged into a pointless debate over which route is "better", or even "best". It reminds me strongly of the endless, pointless "debates" over which electric guitar brands are "best" -- Eric Clapton can create musical marvels on almost any guitar, whereas I never ever will, even if bought the most expensive guitar in the world -- or whether Nikon cameras are "better" than Canon cameras.

Comment: :D Thank you for your patience.